# Multiple dimension matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix `M`, `M.shape` = `(4, 4)` and `M[1,1].shape`=`(600,300)`.
Each `M[i,j]` is calculated by passing a `meshgrid`. For Example

```
x=300
t=np.linspace(0, np.pi, num=x)
p=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,num=2*x)
[T,P]=np.meshgrid(t,p)
M[1,1]=np.sin(T)*np.cos(P)
```

Each element of M is a different combination of `sin` and `cos`.

Next I have `x`, such that `x.shape`=`(4, 600, 300)`. x is calculated as follows:

```
for j in xrange(n):
    x[0]+=np.sin(T)*np.sin(time[j])
    x[1]+=np.sin(T)*np.sin(time[j])
    x[2]+=np.sin(P)*np.cos(time[j])
    x[3]+=np.sin(P)*np.cos(time[j])
```

where `time[j]` is some number.

I want to know how to compute transpose(x).M.X. So this should come to be a quantity of shape(600,300). I have computed `a = np.tensordot(M,x,axes=[1,0])` which yields `a.shape`=`(4,600,300)`.

Firstly, is this correct? Secondly. I how to take the transpose and compute transpose(x).M.x?

Comment: Is ```M.shape``` actually (4,4,600,300)?

Comment: Thats what I thought it should be, but when I run `M.shape` it gives (4,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about how you calculate things like `M` and `x`, and focus on the multiplication:

> I want to know how to compute transpose(x).M.X. So this should come to be a quantity of shape(600,300). I have computed a = np.tensordot(Mat,x,axes=[1,0]) which yields a.shape=(4,600,300).

What is the total shape of `M`?  `wwii`s guess makes most sense `(4,4,600,300)`.

You say `x` is `(4, 600,300)`.  What is `transpose(x)`?  Transpose is defined for 2 axes, but ambiguous with 3.

What is `X`?

what is `Mat`?  The only thing that works in your `np.tensordot(Mat,x,[1,0])` is `(4,4)`.

But let me make an educated guess, you want `X.T * M * X`, but with the added `(600,300)` dimension.

```
 np.einsum('inm,ijnm,jnm->nm', X, M, X)
```

That is, you want a dot produce of `X` with the 1st dim of `M`, and another dot product of `X` with the 2nd dim of `M`, without altering the last 2 dimensions.